# JSDoc: How to set @param for React element as a function param?

Tags: reactjs, intellij-idea, jsx, jsdoc3

What should I add in the JSDoc @param block in the example below for my IntelliJ Webstorm IDE to stop throwing the error: `Argument Type ComponentClass<undefined>` is not assignable to parameter type ??? ... `?

```
/**
 * Renders the passed component into a div
 * @param { ??? } component // Question: <<<
 */
const myRenderFunc = (component) => (
  <div>{component}</div>
)
```

Comment: i think ```*``` should be used if you are not planning to create your own typedef

Comment: thanks was hoping for a built-in integration, but this will do for now.

Answer (score 7):

Your React component `@param` type should be `{ReactElement}`

Comment: To add to this, in order for linters to recognize this correctly (if using the JSDoc plugin) you'll need to import it: `import { ReactElement } from "react"`

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution using `@typedef`

```js
/**
 * @typedef { import('./Question') } Question
 */

/**
 * Renders the passed component into a div
 * @param { Question } component
 */
const myRenderFunc = (component) => (
  <div>{component}</div>
)
```

or if you don't want to use `@typedef`

```js
/**
 * Renders the passed component into a div
 * @param { import('./Question') } component
 */
const myRenderFunc = (component) => (
  <div>{component}</div>
)
```

or if it it doesn't matter that it is a `Question` component, just a React component, you can write `React.ReactElement`. Be aware that you should have React imported in the file or `@typedef`

```js
/**
 * Renders the passed component into a div
 * @param { React.ReactElement } component
 */
const myRenderFunc = (component) => (
  <div>{component}</div>
)
```