# What type to use in JSDoc for the PropType elementType?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsdoc

What type should I use in JSDoc for a prop that is an `elementType`?

```
// A React element type (ie. MyComponent).
optionalElementType: PropTypes.elementType
```

```
/**
 * @param {???} [optionalElementType] - Description
 */
```

Comment: This question already has answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46421680/jsdoc-how-to-set-param-for-react-element-as-a-function-param)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JSDoc: How to set @param for React element as a function param?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46421680/jsdoc-how-to-set-param-for-react-element-as-a-function-param)

Comment: @kellys I'm not sure, I thought the type `ReactElement` was for the PropType `PropTypes.element`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using react's `ElementType`:

```
/**
 * @param {import("react").ElementType} [optionalElementType] - Description
 */
```